# Syntax Error relating back to 'self' not defined

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

Using Flask and SqlAlchemy to create a users table for my website

my models.py looks like this

```
from app import db 

class User(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def__repr__:
        return '[{}]'.format(self.username)
```

However when i try run flask db upgrade in my terminal to properly create the table I get a syntax error relating back to my models.py with self not being defined

Comment: You haven't defined your function correctly, you need to include the parameters to repr

Comment: Missing a space in def __repr__?